# Proof using Archimedean property and Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, soft-question, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the theorem below
(using both the [Archimedean property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) and [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)).
As usual, I would like to write a highly intelligible proof.
Any constructive feedback is appreciated.
Notably, there are the following questions:

1. What is the most unitelligible part of the proof?
2. What is the most $\textit{too-detailed}$ part of the proof?
3. How would you indicate the end of a case
   (see $\textit{Case 1}$ and $\textit{Case 2}$)?
   I tried to use indentation.
   As for longer proofs,
   this could be problematic.
4. Would you prefer to state the theorem as follows?
   $$\forall x > 1, n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists m \in \mathbb{N} : x^m > n$$

---

### Theorem.

Let         $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let         $x \in \mathbb{R}$
such that   $x > 1$.
There is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$
such that   $x^m > n$.

### *Proof.*

Let        $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let        $x \in \mathbb{R}$
such that  $x > 1$.
We define  $y := x - 1$.
Obviously, $y > 0$.
First, we want to show that
there is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
            $my > n - 1$.
To that end, we consider two cases.

$\textbf{Case 1: } n - 1 \le 0$

$\qquad$ We define $m := 1$.
We have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    my &=   1y \\
       &=    y \\
       &>    0 \\
       &\ge  n - 1. \\
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
$\qquad$ Thus, $my > n - 1$.

$\textbf{Case 2: } n - 1 > 0$

$\qquad$ Since both $(n - 1) > 0$ and $y > 0$,
by the Archimedean property,

$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$there is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
                            $my > n - 1$.

It remains to prove that $x^m > n$.
Since $y \ge -1$, by Bernoulli's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    (1 + y    )^m & \ge 1 + my \\
    (1 + x - 1)^m & \ge my + 1 \\
              x^m & \ge my + 1. \\
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Also, since $my > n - 1$, we have $my + 1 > n$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
  x^m > n.
\end{equation*}
QED

Comment: Why does $my + 1 > n$ imply $x^m > n$ ?

Comment: transitivity, $x^m \ge my + 1$